# Get user mail via Podio API without global scope

Tags: api, podio

How can I/my app (=extension) get the user email, if I don't want to use the scope `global:all` (see [Podio scopes](https://developers.podio.com/authentication/scopes))?

I'd expect the scope `user:read` would suffice, but the endpoints `/user` ([Get user](https://developers.podio.com/doc/users/get-user-22378)) and `/user/status` ([Get user status](https://developers.podio.com/doc/users/get-user-status-22480)) both return the following error:

> Must have the permission all on global to perform this operation

Answer (score 2):

You need an authentication scope for the request to work. In the documentation there is a diagram that shows the hierarchy. [1]

If you are referring to "app" in the Podio sense then use the "App" scope.

[1] https://developers.podio.com/authentication/scopes

Edit:

There is a current limitation in the functionality of the user:read scope. This has been filed as an issue and will be updated accordingly.

Comment: @chris-peters-podio : As I stated in the question I am _not_ talking about an Podio-App but an extension. I understand very well, the general concept of scopes with Podio API (the link you posted was already included in my question!). The question was specifically about the endpoint `GET /user` and why one needs global scope for it instead of read scope user??

Comment: Somehow I didn't succeed in tagging @chris correctly in the above comment - did you see that the question is not answered?

Comment: Yes. I understand. Your app is querying the Podio API. You need to specify the desired scope for your request. You don't have to use the global scope you can chose org, space, app, or user depending on how restrictive you'd like to make your scope.

Comment: @daniel-sc Did this resolve your issue? If so can you please check the answer as the correct solution so other users can reference this?

Comment: No this did not answer my question. The podio api is telling me I'd need global scope for reading user info, but to my understanding this should be possible with user-read scope! Am I wrong, is this intended or is this a bug??

Comment: Hello @chris could you please look into this or trigger a colleague? This lets me doubt the auth concept is solid..

Comment: @daniel-sc Yes, I apologize for the delayed response. I got roped into another issue that took all day yesterday. I am looking at the code with a colleague and we are trying to determine the expected behavior. Your question poses a completely valid use case.